# LinearLayout expanding elements

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a imageView and a linear layout inside a linear layout. It looks like this:
[image]

What I want to happen is have the second linear layout with all of the buttons and params be a fixed height, and then have the image view height be dynamic depending on whatever the size of the screen is. So if there is a large screen then the image will be large and the button and sliders will always be the same.

Here is a snippet of what I have:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgPreview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: i recommend to use RelativeLayout as root layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by giving the `ImageView` a `layout_height` of `0dp` and setting its `layout_weight` to `1`. The inner `LinearLayout` will have its `layout_height` set to `wrap_content`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Your button and slider content here>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do this using:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="YOUR VALUE"
```